# I don't understand this question

Tags: combinatorics

You have a craving for Mrs. Fields gourmet cookies. You have a choice of oatmeal raisin, macadamia nut, triple chocolate, cinnamon sugar, chocolate chip, and peanut butter. If you must choose at least one cookie. How many ways is this possible?

Comment: $63{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Nikunj And the comment award goes to ... 

Comment: What is "this"?

Comment: @Henry AFAIK "this" means "choosing at least one out of 6 cookies." A simple combinatorial argument indeed gives $2^6-1$ as the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is perhaps a little ambiguous, but here's one interpretation - there are 6 cookies, one in each of the listed flavours. How many ways can you take *at least one* cookie, but potentially up to all 6?

There are two ways that you can approach this (and if you do it right, they should give you the same results):

Method 1: There are $^6C_1 = 6$ ways to pick a single cookie, $^6C_2 = 15$ ways to pick a pair of cookies, and so forth up to $^6C_6 = 1$ way to pick all 6 cookies. Adding them up will give you the total number of ways to choose at least one cookie.

Method 2: You can either pick oatmeal raisin or leave it out, giving you two options on that front. Once you've decided on that, you can either add macadamia nut or leave it out, again giving you two options, so at this point there are $2 \times 2 = 4$ different possible selections. You can then either add triple chocolate or skip it, so now there are $4 \times 2 = 8$ choices. You keep doing that for all the arrangements, giving you all the ways to pick out of the 6 cookies. **But**, if you look carefully, that set of choices includes the case where you avoid all the cookies, which the problem says isn't happening. So once you have your number, subtract one for the disallowed option.